# How do I change my code to draw a table from this list?

Tags: python

```
seq = [11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]    
           
for i in range(len(seq)):
            print(seq[i],end ="\t")
```

How do I get my output table to look like this?

```
11  34  17  52  26  13  
40  20  10  5   16   8  
4   2   1
```

Comment: use padding or string formatting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Answer (score 0):

one of many ways is this, you make iterate over the `seq` list by a step of 6 and print the element between those margins

```
seq = [11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]    

for i in range(0, len(seq), 6):
    print(*seq[i:i+6], sep=' ')
```

output

```
11 34 17 52 26 13
40 20 10 5 16 8
4 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest relevant technique is padding

```
for i in range(0, len(seq), 6):
    print("  ".join[str(k).ljust(2, " ") for k in seq[i: i + 6]]
```

but string formatting as in [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) will make is a more sophisticated solution

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make use of string formatting. Below, `f"{seq[i]:<4d}"` means "A string of length 4, left-aligned, containing the string representation of `seq[i]`". If you want to right-align, just remove `<`.

```
seq = [11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

for i in range(len(seq)):
    print(f"{seq[i]:<4d}", end = "")

    if not (i+1) % 6:
        print("")

print("")
```

Output:

```
11  34  17  52  26  13
40  20  10  5   16  8
4   2   1
```